# Ruby on Rails: I want to remove non letters to create a username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have the name `"Master Yoda"`

How would I auto convert it to be lowercase, and replace spaces with underscores... or just get rid of the spaces.

so maybe turn it into `master_yoda` 
or `masteryoda`

I'm looking for the most concise solution possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to do this is [`underscore`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001060) from Rails' [`ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::String::Inflections`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001060) module.

As an added note, if any native Rails method doesn't do exactly what you want, make sure to click the "Show source" links at api.rubyonrails.org. In this case, showing the source of `Inflections.underscore` tells us it is actually just calling `Inflector.underscore` on the caller string object.

Searching for that documentation, we can find the method that really does the work (so to speak) here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#M000710

I know you want the most succinct answer, but just know that it is relatively simple (and also beneficial to learn) how things work "under the hood."

Comment: Sorry but that's not right. `"Blah Blah".underscore # => "blah blah"`, `"BLah Blah".underscore # => "b_lah blah"`... the `underscore` method is used for modules and such: `"ActiveRecord::Base".underscore # => "active_record/base"`

Comment: I don't see why I was down voted for my answer... @thenduks, you proposed `underscorize` which doesn't exist. On the other hand, this does what the OP wants and even if it doesn't perfectly, I provide an explanation as to how to modify the code to find something that fits their needs.

Comment: Hmm, I must have a plugin that added underscorize and then misread the docs. So you are right, although `underscore` still isn't intended to be used for this, your suggestion of simply reading the code and writing your own version (perhaps called `underscorize`? :)) makes sense. I deleted my answer and edited the underscorize part out of yours so I could retract my downvote.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging this, you are right however that `Inflector.underscore` does seem to be primarily for usage on string module names, hence the `gsub.(/::/,'/')`. Then again, checking the very readable source should allow the OP to simply find an answer. In any case, I still think this solution is the most succinct, native Rails way of doing this.

Comment: I disagree with this answer as it does not actually answer the posters question.  If telling a user to read the source is a sufficient answer to a question then stack overflow would be much less useful.  Using `gsub(/\s/, '_')` would be a better solution to the posters problem, if in fact there is no rails based solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
'Master Yoda'.underscore # => 'master yoda'
'MasterYoda'.underscore # => 'master_yoda'
'Master Yoda'gsub(' ', '') # => 'MasterYoda'
'Master Yoda'.gsub(' ', '').downcase # => 'masteryoda'
```